# Dealing with Null XML payloads in Jersey

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, jersey

If I send a Null xml payload it throws following exception before hitting the Controller method.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.]
```

But when I send a JSON payload. Jackson api sends a Null Entity Object to the controller method.

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response createEntity(Entity entity) {}
```

How can I achieve Jackson's marshaling behavior with XML Payloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marshaller reacts correct. The minimum expected xml for example for an User class could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user></user>
```

which is in fact an empty User. If you now send this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

there is no starting value for the marshaller and the payload is marked as corrupted. Similar case for sending nothing.

But if you use jersey 2.? (2.12 for me) you can use an `ExceptionMapper` to react on that (sample).

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.NoContentException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException;

@Provider
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException>{

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest cr;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BadRequestException e) {

        String reason = String.format("Reason: %s", e.toString());

        if( e.getCause() instanceof UnmarshalException )
            reason = "Request payload is invalid.";

        if( e.getCause() instanceof NoContentException )
            reason = "No payload given.";

        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity(String.format("%s [resource:%s, contentType:%s, method:%s]", reason, cr.getPathInfo(), cr.getContentType(), cr.getMethod() ) ).build();
    }

}
```

Hope this was helpfull somehow :)

Comment: Thanks for taking time and giving a detailed answer. The only problem is that I am using `Jersey1.17`. Both `NoContentException` and `BadRequestException` are not available in `1.17` version.

Comment: Ah fuu, change version?!? :) - maybe you can find something similar for 1.17 - will press thumbs!